# Is it possible to show the device ID in nautilus properties?

Tags: usb, unetbootin

I use unetbootin to boot ISOs from USB devices, however when it asks me which device to install it to it lists them by device ID(?) ie sdb, sdc etc.

The only way I know to find out which device is which is by going to disk manager. Is a similar effect achievable from the properties page in nautilus? It show me the mount point (/media/drivename) but this does not help me identify the drive by its device id.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure how to show this info in nautilus, but you can also use System Monitor as mounted filesystem are shown in the last tab.